# Google Play Game Services

Tags: java, android, leaderboard

I am developing Android game and I have putted leaderboard in it.Now I want to know what if statement shall I use for opening leaderboard or submiting the score(for stable loading)?

```
if(???){
   startActivityForResult(
                        Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(
                                baseHelper.getApiClient(),
                                getResources().getString(
                                        R.string.leaderboard_time_rush_mode)),
                        1);
}
```

Shall I use `if(gameHelper.isSignedIn())` or `if(gameHelper.isConnecting())`
And the same question for this

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(baseHelper.getApiClient(), getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard), score);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go here. This link has so much information and more on this topic.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards